# Quaternion Hermitian diagonalization

Tags: linear-algebra, quaternions, diagonalization

How do I go about diagonalizing such a matrix.

For example let $D$ be the quaternion algebra over $\mathbb{Q}$ with $i^2 = -1, j^2 = -11$ and take the matrix:

$A = \begin{pmatrix} 11 & -j-3k \\ j+3k & 11 \end{pmatrix}$.

How do I find $P\in$ $GL_2(D)$ such that $\bar{P}^T A P$ is diagonal? Does the non-commutativity create problems with the usual construction?

Comment: Should it it be $j^2 = -1, k^2 = -1$ in the definition of $\mathbb{Q}$? Typo?

Comment: No, I am using a quaternion algebra ramified at $11$.

Comment: The OP has [cross-posted](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/135106/diagonalization-of-quaternion-hermitian-matrices) the question to MO and gotton an answer there.

Comment: Yes I forgot to update this! Thanks...